# Google Play Store seeing different versions

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app which I have been developing for about a year and I just pushed out a new version onto the google play store. I see the new version just fine on my own phone but my girlfriend's phone still sees the previous version.

I switched from eclipse to Android Studio for this release and thus was using Gradle for the first time. But I made fairly sure that the permissions, etc remained the same. One major change that was done was that in the previous version it was only supported up till api 16 but the new version allowed api 15.

I don't get why my girlfriend's phone can't see the new update.

If someone can advise, it would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Edit:

Something stranger about the whole thing is this. On the store listing, I changed the icon, feature graphic and promo graphic as well. The old one still appears on her phone.

Comment: Which android version in your girl friend phone?

Comment: It will take some time till the update is rolled out to all cell phones. You can also try updating manually through playstore.

Comment: please add in the question your friend phone and your application feature/permissions.

Comment: I don't know what version her phone is. But the new version supports api 16+ while the previous version supports only 15+. In theory it should appear as per usual.

It has been about 20 hours since I pushed it up onto google play store, it usually doesn't take any longer than 4-5 hours from previous pushes.

Comment: Both the previous and the new version has the same permissions:

android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE

+ 1 more app specific one

Comment: then maybe your girlfriend phone at API 15 and when you update your app to 16+, your app doesnt support your girlfriend's phone anymore

Comment: No, it's the other way around. The new version supports api 15+ whereas the old version only supports 16+.